# Java 8 edit stream elements

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream, java-11

I need to filter and modify the values of the filtered object.
The logic that must be filtered is given below.

```
    boolean isUpdated = false;
    for (final Identifier identifier : identifiers)
    {
      if (identifier.type == type)
      {
        identifier.identifier = identifierValue;
        identifier.label = label;
        identifier.comment = comment;
        isUpdated = true;
        break;
      }
```

I have tried it like this. But how can we set the value of **isUpdated = true** using java 8?

```
    Arrays.stream(identifiers).filter(a -> a.type == type).forEach(i -> {
      i.identifier = identifierValue;
      i.label = label;
      i.comment = comment;
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on the logic given, [`findFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst()) should be used as you stop after the first instance is found.

```
    boolean isUpdated = false;
    Optional<Identifier> result = Arrays.stream(identifiers).filter(i -> i.type==type).findFirst();
    result.ifPresent(i -> {
        i.identifier = identifierValue;
        i.label = lebel;
        i.comment = comment;
    });
    isUpdated = result.isPresent();
```

Comment: @Holger, Thx, I am about to delete my answer.

Comment: Don’t delete it. It’s valuable for future readers even when the OP decided not to use it.

Answer (score -2):

A "hack" that you can use:

````
boolean[] isUpdated = new boolean[] {false};

Arrays.stream(identifiers).filter(a -> a.type == type).forEach(i -> {
      i.identifier = identifierValue;
      i.label = label;
      i.comment = comment;
      isUpdated[0] = whatever_you_want;
    });```
````

Comment: This code will not yield the same result as OP's code with the enhanced for loop. OP's code will stop after the first occurrence of an element where `identifier.type == type`, due to the `break` statement. Your code, however, will continue to update all elements where `identifier.type == type`, and not just the first one found.